# Add Flutter screens to existing native iOS and Android apps

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a product natively developed in iOS and Android platforms. And they are released onto AppStore and PlayStores.

Our Product Teams wants to add extra features.

How can I develop these new modules, screens in Flutter, Dart and add these to the existing iOS and Android native projects?

The problem is... one of the Flutter screens have to appear as one of the VCs in TabViewController.
The Flutter pages mentions launching the flutter modules on tap of a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the official Flutter docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app) for adding flutter to the existing app also follow along with the [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-flutter-to-existing-android-ios-app-ae8c4fb1582e) which I thought might be useful

Comment: I edited my question. I need to add the new Flutter Screen as one of the VCs in tab controller. How to do that?